# How to center a parent div to the center bottom

Tags: html, css

Hi & Thank you for your time.

I'm new in html and css and there is my problem:

I want to make an HUD using html & css, And I want it be responsive.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="status" style="margin:auto;">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="backpack nothing">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="helmet nothing">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="vest nothing">

    <div class="bullets-container">
      <div class="inmag">
        30
      </div>
      <div class="intotal">
        389
      </div>
    </div>

    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="status nothing">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="healthgen nothing">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="lungs nothing">
  </div>
  <div class="health">

  </div>
</div>
```

Currently it's centered in the middle but I really don't know how to position it in the bottom, Thank you for your help :).

Comment: By default the height is calculated to `fit-content`. To move an element to the bottom you need either give it a height that is higher then the contact or you can position it with a position-attribute such as `position: fixed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue, you need to place a container with a fixed position. From the bottom you need to set the zero position, and from the left edge - in the middle left: 50%. In this case, you need to compensate for the dimensions of the container, this is done using transform: transitionX(-50%).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*added*/
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="status" style="margin:auto;">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="backpack nothing">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="helmet nothing">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="vest nothing">

    <div class="bullets-container">
      <div class="inmag">
        30
      </div>
      <div class="intotal">
        389
      </div>
    </div>

    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="status nothing">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="healthgen nothing">
    <img src="./icon_exm.png" class="lungs nothing">
  </div>
  <div class="health">

  </div>
</div>
```